# Relative size of subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to achieve generate plot made of subplots: `plt.plot()` and `plt.matshow()`, in which two plots had exactly the same size. What I mean is that lower border of one plot and lower borders of second plots were located on same "height". Similarly with the top border line. Current effect is presented on the plot below.

I haven't found any way in the available resources which would help me to achieve this effect. I would be grateful if you could help me.

```
shape=(2500, 2500)
matrix=np.zeros(shape)
print "Start of computing"
for x in range(shape[0]) :
  for y in range(shape[1]) :
    matrix[x, y]=shapeFuction((x-shape[0]/2)/13.0, (y-shape[1]/2)/13.0, 2.0e-4, 9e-5, 1.0)

print "Start of plotting"
fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, aspect=1)
ax.matshow(matrix, cmap="autumn") #data[250:501,150:351])
ax.set(adjustable='datalim', aspect=1)
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.set(adjustable='box-forced') #adjustable='datalim'
ax.grid(b=False)

print "Start of plotting part 2"
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
phase=(9.0e-5*np.power(np.arange(0, shape[1])-shape[1]/2,3 ))/7
g=ax.get_ylim()
asp=shape[1]/float(abs(g[0]-g[1]))
ax.plot(phase) #data[250:501,150:351])
ax.set(adjustable='box-forced')#, aspect=1.06/6.0) #adjustable='datalim''box-forced'
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("Phase")
plt.savefig('testData-x3.png')
# plt.show()
```

[image: Current output plot from the code above]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to set the aspect of the imshow plot (which is usually `1`, such that pixels are squared), to `"auto"`, `ax2.imshow(z, cmap="autumn", aspect="auto")`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3,3)
y = np.tan(x)
z = np.random.rand(30,30)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax.plot(x,y)
ax2.imshow(z, cmap="autumn", aspect="auto")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead you want to keep the aspect ratio of the image plot, you can change the aspect of the line plot by comparing the different axis limits,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3,3)
y = np.tan(x)
z = np.random.rand(30,30)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax.plot(x,y)
ax2.imshow(z, cmap="autumn")

ratio = np.diff(ax.get_ylim())[0]/np.diff(ax.get_xlim())[0]
ratio2 = np.diff(ax2.get_ylim())[0]/np.diff(ax2.get_xlim())[0]
aspect = ratio2/ratio
ax.set_aspect(float(np.abs(aspect)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The second option is what I was looking for. But I get following error which origin I do not understand. Could you look on this also?

`UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if aspect == 'normal':
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif aspect in ('equal', 'auto'):`

Comment: Ok. I just needed to convert it into Python float. Thank you for effective help!

Comment: I edited the line which caused the warning, thanks for pointing that out.